# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=zhanysch@gmail.com }

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

I new in android , i'm attempting open gmail app through Intent , i have clicked on menu bottom for open E-address in gmail , and i have got problem top sentence .
this is my code

```
private fun menuClicks() {
        binding?.toolbar?.toolbar?.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            when(it.itemId){

                R.id.conact ->{
                    val client = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("zhanysch@gmail.com"))
                    startActivity(client)
                    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                }

                R.id.FAQ ->{
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_faqFragment)
                    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                }

                R.id.terms ->{
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_termsConditionsFragment)
                    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                }

                R.id.Privacy -> {
                    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_privacyFragment)
                    return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
                }
                else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

what the problem can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intent for opening Gmail is wrong. I recommend looking into "Send email intent" in Android.

But for the simple case, change this:

```
val client = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("zhanysch@gmail.com"))
```

into this:

```
val client = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:zhanysch@gmail.com"))
```

For a better, more generic solution, I recommend checking the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email).